# In SwiftUI, how can I detect the moment the user lifts his finger off a ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am currently trying to add some "Pull to Reach" functionality in my SwiftUI app. I have a top nav bar with buttons that I would like to allow users to "tap" by pulling on the ScrollView (i.e. continue to drag until the scroll offset is positive). Then, upon letting go, if the scroll offset is beyond a particular amount (e.g. 100), the ScrollView model's is Eligible property will change and some code will run.

I came across the following code snippet which is able to detect very accurately when the user releases touch. However, if I were to update any of the Published variables e.g. isEligible or scrollOffset, the ScrollView starts to glitch and is unable to drag without flickering (and is actually unable to scroll to a positive offset anymore). If I were to comment out any state changes and just run the print statement when the user releases touch, everything works alright and the print statements are timely logged in the console, with no glitching whatsoever. Is there any way I can address this, or is there a way to access `scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)` of a UIScrollView to run a function when the user lets go?

```
class ScrollViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    @Published var isEligible: Bool = false
    @Published var scrollOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @Published var finalOffset: CGFloat = 0
    let gestureID: String = UUID().uuidString
    
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func addGesture() {
        print("ADDING SHIT")
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onGestureChange(gesture: )))
        panGesture.delegate = self
        panGesture.name = gestureID
        rootController().view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }
    
    func removeGesture() {
        rootController().view.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll(where: { gesture in
            gesture.name == gestureID
        })
    }
    
    func rootController() -> UIViewController {
        guard let screen = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else {
            return .init()
        }
        
        guard let root = screen.windows.first?.rootViewController else {
            return .init()
        }
        
        return root
    }
    
    @objc
    func onGestureChange(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.state == .cancelled || gesture.state == .ended {

            print("released")
            
            if scrollOffset > 50 {
                isEligible = true
            } else {
                isEligible = false
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```